# Symfony2 - Random Failed to start the session

Tags: symfony, session

We have a site with Symfony2 with some traffic.

Every day the site begins to fail with this error for 1 or 2 minutes (15-20 errors). This occurs at random hours, could not find a pattern. It does not fit even to peak hours.

```
2015-10-09 02:23:57.635 [2015-10-09 06:23:38] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception RuntimeException: "Failed to start the session" at /var/www/thing.com/httpdocs/app/cache/prod/classes.php line 121 {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): Failed to start the session at /var/www/thing.com/httpdocs/app/cache/prod/classes.php:121)"} []
```

Doesn't seem to be a double header problem or double start problem.
Site does not interact with any PHP legacy code that could be messing with the sessions.

Sessions are stored in the database so a file problem is discarded.
Lowered the session duration so the session table does not get too big and the problem persists.

Think It could be a problem with HWIOAuthBundle and it's facebook login, but cannot find where is the conflict.

Also the site uses a lot of render_esi for caching with Symfony2 internal cache system.

Update -------------------------------------------------

Emptied the /var/lib/php/sessions folder of older session files than were not being used.

Lowered the session lifespan. Sql entries in the sessions table went from ~3 Million to ~1.3 Million.

Seems that the problem is gone but this is not a real solution.
My guess is that the pdo_handler in symfony2 has a performance problem.

Maybe someone with more knowledge in this matter (pdo_handler, table optimization) can point a real solution for high traffic.

Answer (score 1):

Where does your PHP installation save sessions to?

[You can find this in your php.ini file in the session.save_path setting, assuming you have CLI access]

It is very likely PHP uses your servers /tmp folder. If this folder is full at any point, then PHP can't create new sessions.

You can see the current size of your /tmp folder with:

```
du -ch /tmp/ |grep total
```

If, as is common, the /tmp folder is on its own partition, you can see its maximum size with :

```
df -h
```

Some programs can suddenly guzzle Gbs of this folder for their purposes.

Comment: Might be onto something. The folder /var/lib/php/session is 6.3 GB. Why are so much PHP sessions being stored when we are using the symfony2 sessions in database?

Comment: That is a _LOT_ of session data, indeed. What are you storing in your sessions?

Comment: This page might put you on the right path: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/session/sessions_directory.html

Comment: @Nodens: If you have that many session data, apparently the garbage collection doesn't work. (GC refering to removing old sessions in this context.) So either PHP is not set up to garbage-collect old sessions itself (i.e. there's some independent cronjob). Or it is looking in the wrong folder, not the one where Symfony puts its stuff.

Comment: Deleted the whole content of /var/lib/php/session and now it's empty. There are no new files being created but the sudden errors are still there. I guess the big session folder wasn't the issue. Still searching.